# Find first of many elements in python - text.find(a , b , c)

Tags: text, scripting, find, python

I want to check if one of the words in "a" is within "text"

```
text = "testing if this works"
a = ['asd' , 'test']
print text.find(a)
```

how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check whether any of the words in `a` is in text, use, well, [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(word in text  for word in a)
```

If you want to know the number of words in `a` that occur in text, you can simply [`add`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) them:

```
print('Number of words in a that match text: %s' %
      sum(word in text  for word in a))
```

If you want to only match full words (i.e. you don't want to match `test` the word `testing`),  split the text into words, as in:

```
words = set(text.split())
any(word in words  for word in a)
```

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves No offense, but your edit changed the meaning of this answer by quite a bit. Plus, it would be very inefficient for a large number of words and a non-optimizing Python interpreter which would constantly split text. Added your version, but optimized it beforehand.

Comment: Sorry. I'd read the question as wanting to search for whole words, so tried to make the minimal edit to fit that interpretation. Looking back I see that the question is actually ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: wordset = set(text.split())

In [21]: any(w in wordset for w in a)
Out[21]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexes can be used to search for multiple match patterns in a single pass:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ['asd' , 'test']
>>> regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True))))

>>> print bool(regex.search(text))       # determine whether there are any matches
True
>>> print regex.findall(text)            # extract all matching text
['test']
>>> regex.search(text).start()           # find the position of the first match
0
```